# Style select menu

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to style a <select> menu like the following image:

[image: a select menu]

Here is a fiddle that I have been working on but can not get the arrow correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/nmpxj/

Here is the HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>Alabama</option>
  <option>Alaska</option>
</select>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
select {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#C9C9C9, #CCC);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#C9C9C9, #CCC);
border: 1px solid #ccc;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);    
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
padding:10px;
}
```

Is it possible to style a <select> menu like this?

Comment: I don't get it, can you elaborate further? The select menu's box is separated from the arrow... what do you mean separate?

Comment: I editted the question with an image to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: I think you want something like this: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: you may try this one http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Comment: Thank you drneel!  I had not run across that site yet in my search but it looks promising.  I will give that shot.

Comment: Is this a select box for a form that you will later submit? Or are you using the select as a dropdown menu that when the user clicks on an option something happens? If the second, you can do this using other elements and style this as you want.

Comment: Could you provide the link of the example's picture?

Answer (score 1):

The way you need to do it is basically float them both left and clear their right's as follows

```
select { float:left; clear:right; }
div { float:left; clear:right; }
```

This will push them close together. Also you shouldn't use the `<p>` tag beside the select box. Put the arrow inside a div instead there is no reason not to and it will remove the space when you float them as well. It is just cleaner coding to do it this way.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm trying to figure out.  II updated the question and provided an image for what I have been trying to accomplish, and I apologize for the unclear question I originally posted.  I see there's a lot out there on the web for trying to style select menus but nothings really helped me.  Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your css:

```
width: auto;  
background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol/icons/arrow_sans_down_32.png') no-repeat right;
```

That should do the trick.

Demo: [Select Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nmpxj/11/)